# Jquery Inputmask token in mask

Tags: jquery

I am using the [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) plugin and have recently run into an issue. We're using the plugin to format input fields for different telephone numbers per country, for example:

```
+1 (___) ___-____ [+1 (999) 999-9999]
```

The North American Numbering plan.

```
+33 __-__-__-__ [+33 99-99-99-99]
```

The french numbering plan.

These work, but the issue arises when we hit Germany.

```
+4_ ___-___-___ [+49 999-999-999]
```

The 9 is the number used by the input mask plugin. It incorrectly believes the literal `+49` we want to add to the field is part of the values the mask is taking.  We need to allow 9 to show up in the mask and not be considered a token. Is there a way to change the numeric mask indicator from 9 to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the 9:

`$(".german").inputmask('+4\\9 999-999-999');`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A63vW/)**

Comment: This looks great, we'll use this and simply escape any 9's we need to persist as literal characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new mask definition:

```
$.extend($.inputmask.defaults.definitions, {
    'n': {  //masksymbol
        "validator": "[0-9]",
        "cardinality": 1
    }
}
```

And then your mask should looks like:

```
[+4n nnn-nnn-nnn]
```

Comment: I tried this and it looked promising at first, the issue is, the '9' mask still exists, so any 9's are still getting parsed, for example n9n-n9n would still yield ___-___.